# Dynamic object keys... Cannot create property on string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an input automatically store its value in an object. The key should be the input's id. Ex: {screen1_input1: 'whatever'}. The first character does that. The second character crashes with "TypeError: Cannot create property on string". I think I see what's happening but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function Demo() {
    const [contentData, setContentData] = useState({})
    
    const onChange = (e) => {
        let oldData = contentData
        setContentData(oldData[e.target.id] = e.target.value)
        console.log('*')
    }
    
    const Screen1 = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <input type="text" id="screen1_input1" onChange={onChange} />
            </>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <h2 className="Demo">
                {Screen1()}
            </h2>
        </>
    )
}

export default Demo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

- The assignment operator resolves to a value of the value assigned. So

```
setContentData(oldData[e.target.id] = e.target.value)
```

is like

```
oldData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
setContentData(e.target.value)
```

which is causing issues because in the next render, `contentData` becomes a string instead of the object.

- Never mutate state in React. Instead, create a *new* object:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    setContentData({
        ...contentData,
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`setContentData(oldData[e.target.id] = e.target.value)` is not a valid format. You can create a `newData` object to copy the last `contentData` and add a new dynamic key-value.

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    const newData = {
      ...contentData,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }
    setContentData(newData)
    console.log('*')
}
```